# Service or Broadcast receive for scheduling long background work (e.g. SMS scheduling ) ???

Tags: android, service, sms, schedule

I need a help to develop a apps for sending sms in future time by scheduling the time and date .... Please help me by suggesting or give some example....

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to know how to send a SMS using Android API. For that you can check this example which explains it:

http://www.mkyong.com/android/how-to-send-sms-message-in-android/

For scheduling tasks, just take a look at [ScheduledExecutorService](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html). Joining both ideas you will get what you want for sure.

**Edit:**

As asked by @BDAndroidLover about long background works, here is the description and aim of a Service in Android:

> A Service is an application component that can perform long-running
>   operations in the background and does not provide a user interface.
>   Another application component can start a service and it will continue
>   to run in the background even if the user switches to another
>   application. Additionally, a component can bind to a service to
>   interact with it and even perform interprocess communication (IPC).
>   For example, a service might handle network transactions, play music,
>   perform file I/O, or interact with a content provider, all from the
>   background.

Because of that, a [Service](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) is the best solution for that purpose.

Comment: I know how to send SMS. But i can't understand scheduling tasks..
Besides, I need to know which is the perfect for scheduling long background work ? Service or Broadcast Receiver ?

Comment: Edited the main answer for that